# Read and write to console in Windows CMD Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I read numbers from **STDIN** and print their sum to **STDOUT** in Windows CMD using Batch-script language?

Like it's working in bash for example:

```
read a b; expr $a + $b
```

Where is a simple way to install Batch language on [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/)? Is this language popular at all, or do pro Windows users install bash?

Answer (score 5):

Batch is quite hard compared to Bash, because there are not so many commands and the commands are quite limited. However, it's possible:

```
@echo off
set /p number="Enter number: " 
set /p number2="Enter another number: " 
set /a "result=%number%+%number2%"
echo %result%
```

`set /p` prompts for user input. `set /a` will perform an arithmetic operation. When being used, variables are enclosed in `%` like Windows environment variables.

`@echo off` is typically the first line of a batch file. It prevents the commands being output on the console as well. You would not use it in an interactive console, or the typical DOS prompt would disappear.

I am not aware of a Batch port for Ubuntu. I doubt anyone would like to do that, since the Linux utilities are so much more powerful. Also, since Microsoft might change their closed source implementation, people would need to reverse engineer the behavior.

Comment: why you add @echo off? Does it make sense?

Comment: @Evgeny: it's usually the first line in a batch file. It prevents every command to be repeated in the output

Comment: should I use @echo off in interactive mode in console?

Comment: @Evgeny: no, you would lose the command line prompt that way

Comment: @ThomasWeller, it should be `set /a "result=number+number2"` In the `set /a` command any non-numeric strings in the expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are converted to numbers before using them. Additionally it is important to mention that `set /a` is limited to 32-bit signed integers for its decimal math.

Comment: @Compo: I tried my code and it worked with % as well

Comment: I didn't say that it doesn't work like that, in this scenario @ThomasWeller, but it is not the correct way to do it. Microsoft tells you that the `%` characters aren't needed, not me, if you don't want to improve your code, then don't, it's no loss to me, but at least future readers may learn something, and improve theirs.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough and much more readable in PowerShell. And, PowerShell runs on Linux, Mac, and even Windows. The same code runs without change. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

```
$number = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter number'
$number2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter another number'
$result = [int]$number + [int]$number2
Write-Host "The result is $($result)"
```

If you must do this from a cmd.exe prompt or in a .bat script file:

```
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$number = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter number';" ^
    "$number2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter another number';" ^
    "$result = [int]$number + [int]$number2"; ^
    "Write-Host "The result is $($result)""
```